# Ubuntu 14.04 Gnome shell display changed. How to restore default

Tags: 14.04, command-line, gnome-terminal

On ubuntu 14.04, default GNOME Terminal, its behavior changed. By example, when I do `cd ~/Download/` I expect the following:

[image]

But I get the following, without the `username@computername:path$`

[image]

**Any idea how to fix this ?**

Comment: Are you still running bash?

Comment: Fine. I was using Powershell, a skin for shell, and moved that folder without noticing it so my shell ended up without any skin, only the most basic behavior. I restored my skin, it's now fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question Solved by Original Poster:

[Ubuntu 14.04 Gnome shell display changed. How to restore default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/555540/ubuntu-14-04-gnome-shell-display-changed-how-to-restore-default#comment763146_555540)

Just forgot to restore the original skin for the Shell.